# my project spring boot not deploy in glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, glassfish-4

My problem arises in the deploy of glassfish and if execute springApplication the project execute good.

my project does not deploy in glassfish, I add my build gradle and stscktrace:

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.M2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.prospectiva'
version = '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}


dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging")
    testCompile(group: "org.junit.jupiter", name: "junit-jupiter-engine", version: "5.0.1")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile group: "mysql", name: "mysql-connector-java", version: "5.1.9"
    compile group: "org.json", name: "json", version: "20160212"
    compile group: "com.google.code.gson", name: "gson", version: "2.8.0"
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'


    // configuration annotation
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")

    compile 'org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0'

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'
}

bootWar {
    baseName = 'Mexichem'
    version = '1.0'
}
```

My server.log:

```
[2019-04-08T15:47:04.857-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=80 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1554756424857] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class of size 697
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:04.882-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=80 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1554756424882] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/internal/DefaultObjectInputFilter.class of size 2913
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:04.885-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=80 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1554756424885] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class of size 7264
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:04.888-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=80 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1554756424888] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class of size 778
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:07.382-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-SECURITY-05054] [javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756427382] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      The SSL certificate has expired: [
    [
      Version: V3
      Subject: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
      Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

      Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
      modulus: 135786214035069526348186531221551781468391756233528066061569654028671100866720352830303278016129003918213826297308054231261658522889438712013757624116391437358730449661353175673177742307421061340003741057138887918110217006515773038453829253517076741780039735595086881329494037450587568122088113584549069375417
      public exponent: 65537
      Validity: [From: Sat Aug 22 11:41:51 CDT 1998,
                   To: Wed Aug 22 11:41:51 CDT 2018]
      Issuer: OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US
      SerialNumber: [    35def4cf]

    Certificate Extensions: 7
    [1]: ObjectId: 1.2.840.113533.7.65.0 Criticality=false
    Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
    0000: 04 0D 30 0B 1B 05 56 33   2E 30 63 03 02 06 C0     ..0...V3.0c....


    [2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
    AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
    KeyIdentifier [
    0000: 48 E6 68 F9 2B D2 B2 95   D7 47 D8 23 20 10 4F 33  H.h.+....G.# .O3
    0010: 98 90 9F D4                                        ....
    ]
    ]

    [3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
    BasicConstraints:[
      CA:true
      PathLen:2147483647
    ]

    [4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
    CRLDistributionPoints [
      [DistributionPoint:
         [CN=CRL1, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority, O=Equifax, C=US]
    ]]

    [5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
    KeyUsage [
      Key_CertSign
      Crl_Sign
    ]

    [6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.16 Criticality=false
    PrivateKeyUsage: [
    To: Wed Aug 22 11:41:51 CDT 2018]

    [7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
    SubjectKeyIdentifier [
    KeyIdentifier [
    0000: 48 E6 68 F9 2B D2 B2 95   D7 47 D8 23 20 10 4F 33  H.h.+....G.# .O3
    0010: 98 90 9F D4                                        ....
    ]
    ]

    ]
      Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
      Signature:
    0000: 58 CE 29 EA FC F7 DE B5   CE 02 B9 17 B5 85 D1 B9  X.).............
    0010: E3 E0 95 CC 25 31 0D 00   A6 92 6E 7F B6 92 63 9E  ....%1....n...c.
    0020: 50 95 D1 9A 6F E4 11 DE   63 85 6E 98 EE A8 FF 5A  P...o...c.n....Z
    0030: C8 D3 55 B2 66 71 57 DE   C0 21 EB 3D 2A A7 23 49  ..U.fqW..!.=*.#I
    0040: 01 04 86 42 7B FC EE 7F   A2 16 52 B5 67 67 D3 40  ...B......R.gg.@
    0050: DB 3B 26 58 B2 28 77 3D   AE 14 77 61 D6 FA 2A 66  .;&X.(w=..wa..*f
    0060: 27 A0 0D FA A7 73 5C EA   70 F1 94 21 65 44 5F FA  '....s\.p..!eD_.
    0070: FC EF 29 68 A9 A2 87 79   EF 79 EF 4F AC 07 77 38  ..)h...y.y.O..w8

    ]]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:07.387-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-SECURITY-05054] [javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756427387] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      The SSL certificate has expired: [
    [
      Version: V1
      Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
      Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4

      Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
      modulus: 104674226241368487598835828377585222181792546532354327780214427055917513664449991602803276678454577364904540367827644455215731003386468752240014232146814457308076052176227490263634768927290191763858631579785604655038492469791381988347440106477066514204303723029602991655085187937840556671697442212352844587673
      public exponent: 65537
      Validity: [From: Wed Aug 12 19:29:00 CDT 1998,
                   To: Mon Aug 13 18:59:00 CDT 2018]
      Issuer: CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
      SerialNumber: [    01a5]

    ]
      Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
      Signature:
    0000: 6D EB 1B 09 E9 5E D9 51   DB 67 22 61 A4 2A 3C 48  m....^.Q.g"a.*<H
    0010: 77 E3 A0 7C A6 DE 73 A2   14 03 85 3D FB AB 0E 30  w.....s....=...0
    0020: C5 83 16 33 81 13 08 9E   7B 34 4E DF 40 C8 74 D7  ...3.....4N.@.t.
    0030: B9 7D DC F4 76 55 7D 9B   63 54 18 E9 F0 EA F3 5C  ....vU..cT.....\
    0040: B1 D9 8B 42 1E B9 C0 95   4E BA FA D5 E2 7C F5 68  ...B....N......h
    0050: 61 BF 8E EC 05 97 5F 5B   B0 D7 A3 85 34 C4 24 A7  a....._[....4.$.
    0060: 0D 0F 95 93 EF CB 94 D8   9E 1F 9D 5C 85 6D C7 AA  ...........\.m..
    0070: AE 4F 1F 22 B5 CD 95 AD   BA A7 CC F9 AB 0B 7A 7F  .O."..........z.

    ]]]
    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.465-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429465] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.467-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429467] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.468-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429468] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.468-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429468] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.469-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429469] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.469-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429469] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.470-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429470] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.470-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429470] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.471-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429471] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.472-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429472] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.473-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429473] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.473-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429473] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.474-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429474] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.474-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429474] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.475-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429475] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.537-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429537] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Class [ com/querydsl/jpa/JPQLQuery ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QuerydslRepositorySupport ]]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.609-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429609] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.609-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429609] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.610-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429610] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.611-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429611] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.611-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429611] [levelValue: 800] [[
      visiting unvisited references]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.644-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429644] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Class [ Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientOptions; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration ]]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.669-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429669] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Class [ com/samskivert/mustache/Mustache$Collector ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration ]]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.670-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429670] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Class [ Lcom/mongodb/async/client/MongoClientSettings; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration ]]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.683-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429683] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Class [ Lcom/unboundid/ldap/listener/InMemoryDirectoryServer; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.embedded.EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration ]]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.690-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429690] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Class [ Lgroovy/text/markup/MarkupTemplateEngine; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration$GroovyMarkupConfiguration ]]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.778-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429778] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Class [ org/thymeleaf/spring5/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration ]]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.807-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429807] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while deploying the app [Mexichem-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.807-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429807] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception during lifecycle processing
    java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
        at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
        at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
        at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)
        at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:285)
        at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:195)
        at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:626)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
        at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:338)
        at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:420)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ]]

    [2019-04-08T15:47:09.862-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1554756429862] [levelValue: 1000] [[
      Exception while deploying the app [Mexichem-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT] : sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy]]
```

delete some log info

I read that it may be spring error and its embedded Tomcat

version SpringBoot 2.0.0
Version Glassfish 4.1
JDK 1.8
IDE intellij
please HELP!!! XD